# Issue in updating security patches for Microsoft windows

Tags: security, patch, windows-server-2008-r2

I have windows server 2008 R2 Standard. Now when I am going to update security patches into it, I am getting errors which are,
Error Code: 80092004
Error Code: 80072EE2

Please help me on this if someone knows about these error code.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing manually KB4490628. It is needed to continue to receive security updates because Windows has switched to SHA-2.

You can find a download link here for x64:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=1d4f0343-a41a-4782-8aed-18a620431171